# How to get base URL to redirect to url/home?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes

When I run my web app it doesn't work because the default URL it opens is http://localhost/WTM/. For some reason that url gives errors but http://localhost/WTM/Home/ works fine, even though it seems to be trying to open the same page.

How do I get the standard url to redirect automatically to url/home? or how do I do the opposite? set my default to the url without /home)

This is my route config code:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: This isn't ASP.NET Core code. Looks like ASP.NET MVC, which is not the same thing.

Comment: whoops, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to add another Route which would look like

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "WTM",
            url: "WTM/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "WTM", action = "Home"}
        );
```

Now if you try http://localhost/WTM/ this will redirect you to Home action of that controller.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. However, it's not working. with that code I'm getting a "forbidden" message on http://localhost/WTM/ and a "not found" on http://localhost/WTM/Home/

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information on the error?

As you can see by the routes provided; the controller (if not specified) will default to Home and the action to Index.

With that in mind http://localhost/WTM, http://localhost/WTM/Home, and http://localhost/WTM/Home/Index should all go to the same controller action.